# Showing lower-semi-continuity of a function.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

Let $f_\lambda: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} (\lambda \in \Lambda)$ be a family of continuous functions. Let 
$$ F(x) = \sup_{\lambda \in \Lambda} f_\lambda (x), x \in \mathbb{R}.$$ 
Show that $F$ is lower-semi-continuous.

My attempt:

We must show that $\liminf_{x \rightarrow x_0} F(x) \geq F(x_0)$ for all $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$.
Since each $f_\lambda$ is continuous, it is also lower-semi-continuous. Thus, $$\liminf_{x \rightarrow x_0} f_\lambda(x) \geq f_\lambda (x_0).$$

Is it true then that $\liminf_{x \rightarrow x_0} \sup f_\lambda(x) \geq \sup f_\lambda (x_0)$? Why? Is there a way I should justify this?

Is it because $\liminf_{x \rightarrow x_0} \sup f_\lambda(x) \geq \sup (\liminf_{x \rightarrow x_0} f_\lambda(x)) \geq \sup f_\lambda (x_0)?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon >0$, By definition of $\sup$, there is a $\lambda \in \Lambda $ such that $F(x_0)-\epsilon<f_{\lambda}(x_0)$. As $f_{\lambda}$ is continuous there is a neighborhood $U$ containing $x_0$ such that $F(x_0)-\epsilon<f_{\lambda}(x)$ whenever $x\in U$. But $f_{\lambda}\le F$ so in fact $F(x_0)-\epsilon<F(x)$.

This is one of the equivalent definitions of lower-semicontinuity so we are done. But to prove that this definition coincides with the one you are using, choose $N\in \mathbb N$ so that $(x_0-1/N,x_0+1/N)\in U$. Then if $n\ge N$,

$F(x_0)-\epsilon<F(x)$ for all $x\in U_n \doteq (x_0-1/n,x_0+1/n)$, which implies  $F(x_0)-\epsilon\le\inf_{x\in U_n}F(x)$ for all $n\ge N$ which means that $F(x_0)-\epsilon\le \lim_{n\to \infty}\inf_{x\in U_n}F(x)$. The result now follows because $\epsilon $ is arbitrary.